# It's about subclass and superclass

Tags: java, inheritance

I would like to ask some concepts:
The object of the subclass belongs to the parent superclass. 
Does the method of the parent class exist in the memory of the subclass? that is, copy the attributes and methods of the parent class to the subclass？or
How do subclass objects manipulate the attributes and methods of the parent class?

thx.

Comment: Consider whatever is in the superclass, is actually in the subclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The object of the subclass belongs to the parent superclass.

"Belongs to" is poor terminology.  A better way to say this is that an object that is an *instance of* a class `C` is also an *instance of* `C`'s immediate superclass.  (In fact, it is an *instance of* all of the superclasses of `C`.)

> Does the method of the parent class exist in the memory of the subclass?

You have a fundamental misconception here.  Methods do no exist in the memory of a class.  Or the memory of an instance.

They are actually held in memory separate to both classes and instance.

The closest that anything comes to what you are saying is that a class *descriptor* will include *internal references* to methods.   But that is all hidden from view, and the details should not concern you.

By contrast, the (non-`static`) attributes of an object (defined by the class) are actually part of the object.   And indeed the attributes defined by the subclasses and all superclasses are *all* part of the same object.

Think of it this way:

- An Animal has legs.
- A Cat is an Animal.
- A Dog is an Animal.
- A Cat has whiskers.
- The legs of a fido the Dog are part of fido.
- The legs of a fluffy the Cat are part of fluffy.
- The whiskers of fluffy the Cat are part of fluffy.

> How do subclass objects manipulate the attributes and methods of the parent class?

Objects don't "manipulate" methods.  They call them.  How they call them is implementation dependent, but *conceptually* they find them in the class descriptor.

A method access attributes by looking at the object via its reference.  Since the subclass and superclass attributes all belong to the same object (see above!!), they are accessed the same way.

Answer (score 0):

It just literally extends it. It's like you would take superclass body and add code of subclass to it to create new class.

There are some minor differences like ability to have 2 versions of the same method in subclass like `methodA()` and `super.methodA()` or that instance of `Subclass` can be treated as `Subclass` and `Superclass` (polymorphism).

But in general you can think of it in such way of subclass having all properties and definitions of subclass.

Comment: private members also difference. but inheritance mostly behave as one class

Comment: Yep they are not visible to subclass, but still there. Thats why that is not the same, but it can be though as it in context of what OP asked - IMHO obviously.